# StreamBridge not sending acknowledgment header

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

KafkaTemplate is sending acknowledgment header but when we send the message from StreamBridge acknowledgment is being sent.
Application.properties:

```
server.port=8082
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=sink1;sink2

spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.sink1-in-0=inbound-events
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inbound-events.group=ama1-channel-group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inbound-events.destination=squaredNumbers-test4
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inbound-events.consumer.header-mode=headers
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inbound-events.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.inbound-events.consumer.ack-mode=manual

spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.sink2-in-0=inbound-stream
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inbound-stream.group=ama2-channel-group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inbound-stream.destination=squaredNumbers-test5
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inbound-stream.consumer.header-mode=headers
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inbound-stream.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.inbound-stream.consumer.ack-mode=manual
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
    BindingServiceProperties bindingProperties;
    StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Autowired
    public KafkaConsumer(final BindingServiceProperties bindingServiceProperties, StreamBridge streamBridge) {
        this.bindingProperties = bindingServiceProperties;
        this.streamBridge = streamBridge;
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message> sink1() {
        return (message) -> {
            System.out.println("******************");
            System.out.println("At Sink1");
            System.out.println("******************");
            System.out.println("Received message " + message);
            streamBridge.send("inbound-stream",MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message> sink2() {
        return (message) -> {
            System.out.println("******************");
            System.out.println("At Sink2");
            System.out.println("******************");
            System.out.println("Received message " + message);

        };
    }
}
```

Main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "demo")
public class MultipleFunctionsApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MultipleFunctionsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>multi-functions-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>multi-functions-kafka</name>
    <description>Spring Cloud Stream Sample Multiple functions Kafka</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

My use case: We receiving events from DB and we are trying to send them to channel using StreamBridge. We want manually ack the events.

Please suggest if I am missing something.
spring-cloud-dependencies : 2021.0.5

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Show code/config as text, not an image and explain what you mean by sending an acknowledgment.

Comment: Hi Gary, I have edited the question. Let me know if something is missing.

Comment: You can't send the acknowledgment header to an output topic, it is a live object that is only relevant in the context of the current application.

Comment: oh okay, but when I send the payload from the database using KafkaTemplate then I receive the ack header at Consumer which is in the same application. But when I send it using streamBridge then I don't receive. Now we are using KafkaTemplate to send. I just wanted to know if it is expected behavior.  The above application is just what I took from stream samples if the same behavior is there.

Comment: What you are saying makes no sense; the `KafkaTemplate` doesn't "send" an acknowledgment, it is created on the consumer side (if the configuration is correct). If you are saying that one of `sink1()`, `sink2()` gets a header, but the other one doesn't, then there is something wrong with the configuration. The presence, or not, of an ack has nothing to do with the producer, only the consumer. If you can't figure it out, post a [complete, minimal, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Correct Gary. I used the above application as an example and  using Kafka cli published a simple Hello message to `squaredNumbers-test4` channel which on consuming publishes the same message to `squaredNumbers-test5`. Now ack header is present at `sink1()` but not at `sink2()`. Now I am not sure what is different about sink2. Thanks. There is no additional configuration is there apart from application.properties which I pasted above.

Comment: It's because you are bypassing `Kafka` by sending it directly to the other channel - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are doing this

```
streamBridge.send("inbound-stream",MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message));
```

You are simply sending the message directly to the other binding's input channel. This bypasses all the Kafka logic; you need to send the record to Kafka, not directly to the input binding's channel.

When using a `KafkaTemplate` instead it is, of course, going via `Kafka`; that's why you are seeing different behavior.

You need an output binding with `inbound-stream` as its destination.

Comment: Thanks, Gary, this is what I was missing.